# Cannot read new files(JSON) after re-sign the APK

Tags: android, json, apk, rebuild

I want to add new JSON files in APK. I followed following steps:

1. Change the extension of my `.apk` to `.zip`
2. Open and remove the folder `META-INF`
3. Added my new files in `assets/`
4. change the extension to `.apk`
5. Use the `jarsigner` and `zipalign` with `keystore`.

I can successfully resign the apk and i can install in device also i can see my new files in the apk(when i unzip the apk).

**But i cant read data from my new added JSON.**

Can anyone help in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You generate an `.apk` not with zip (I supposed that's what you did between step 3 and 4) but with e.g.

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```